# 'Manager' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i'm using Django rest Framework to build an app , iwant to change the language of the app when the user want to change it ,so i made two serializers for each dynamic titles i have in the app one for english and the other for arabic ,i want to give another params called lang to change the response of the api view to use another serializer

==> models.py

```
class RewardSubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'RewardCategory', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ar_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_upload)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)

class RewardCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ar_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_upload)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

==> serializers.py

```
class RewardSubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
window = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
affilates = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = models.RewardSubCategory
    fields = ('id', 'category', 'title', 'picture', 'window', 'affilates')
    depth = 1

def get_window(self, obj):
    windows = models.SubCategoryWindow.objects.filter(
        sub_category=int(obj.id))
    data = SubCategoryWindowSerializer(windows, many=True).data
    return data

def get_affilates(self, obj):
    affilates = models.affilate.objects.filter(sub_category=int(obj.id))
    data = AffilateSerializer(affilates, many=True).data
    return data


class ArabicRewardSubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
window = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
affilates = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = models.RewardSubCategory
    exclude = ('title')
    depth = 1

def get_window(self, obj):
    windows = models.SubCategoryWindow.objects.filter(
        sub_category=int(obj.id))
    data = SubCategoryWindowSerializer(windows, many=True).data
    return data

def get_affilates(self, obj):
    affilates = models.affilate.objects.filter(sub_category=int(obj.id))
    data = AffilateSerializer(affilates, many=True).data
    return data
```

==> views.py

```
class RewardSubCategoryViewSet(FilterSearch, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
"""
    ................. API V1 .................
    Returns subcategories
"""
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (permissions.LoggedInPermission,)
serializer_class = serializers.RewardSubCategorySerializer
queryset = models.RewardSubCategory.objects
filter_fields = ('category')

def get_serializer_class(self):
    lang = self.request.query_params.get('lang')
    if lang == "ar":
        return serializers.ArabicRewardSubCategorySerializer
    return serializers.RewardSubCategorySerializer
```

==>error when i enter in postman query params lang = ar

```
                    TypeError at /v1/reward-subcategories/
            'Manager' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

            Request Method: GET
            Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/reward-subcategories/?lang=ar
            Django Version: 1.11.23
```

Comment: What handler is being called for this route? http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/reward-subcategories/?lang=ar

Comment: There's too much information here, and not enough for us to recreate the problem. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @blueteeth i;m sorry i'm still new i can't understand what you mean by handler is being called ?

Comment: `queryset = models.RewardSubCategory.objects` this should be `queryset = models.RewardSubCategory.objects.all()` because in first case it returns model `Manager` instance and in second case the queryset (and that's what you need)